# Rendering mathematical notation in Python / OpenGL?

Tags: python, math, opengl, rendering, pyglet

How can I render mathematical notations / expressions in Python with OpenGL?

I'm actually using [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) however it uses OpenGL.

Such things as [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula#Quadratic_formula):

[image: Quadratic formula]

I can't store static images as I am generating the expressions as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say generate suitable [latex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) expression, rendering it into an image, then load the image as a texture.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB opengl extension to quickly load dynamicaly generated image of arbitrary size into OpenGL texture. 
You can look for python examples of using dynamic vector graphics with opengl at http://cairographics.org/OpenGL/, though if you want to render complex formulas you also have to look at the some appropriate system like latex.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the OpenGL bit. But [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) has a [`matplotlib.mathtext`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/mathtext_api.html#module-matplotlib.mathtext) module for rendering a sub-set of TeX mathematical expressions.

- [Screenshots](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/screenshots.html#mathtext-examples)
- [Tutorial](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/mathtext.html)